# Редирект от iframe срабатывает на хостинге, а на локалке - нет

Tags: html, javascript

Всё работало на локалке нормально, вводится слово, срабатывает `iframe` с yandex'ом и всё хорошо.
Но стоило закинуть на хостинг, как менее чем через секунду срабатывает редирект на сам яндекс.
Почему так происходит?
(проверял и на платном и на бесплатном хостинге, везде редиректит!)

***[Пример тут](http://jsfiddle.net/qTh9r/3/)***.

Как этого избежать?
(заметил, что редиректит как бы сам яндекс, попробовал с др.сайтом, там нормально.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не любит Яндекс запускаться во фрейме, ну не любит. Если хотите что-то найти с помощью его поиска, есть два пути:
1) Установить встроенный поиск Яндекса.
2) Делать запрос к своему серверному скрипту, который бы тянул данные с Яндекса. Скажем, curl'ом.

Comment: Ок, У меня скрипт, делал поиск с выбором Региона для поиска фразы.
А про тянуть данные curl'ом, это как-то не делал ни разу.
Спасибо за подсказку на решение.